# Keyboard keeps typing ]]] by itself

Tags: keyboard, virus

1. During start up beeping sound came out (sound came recently)
2. When I log in, it types automatically with `]]]]]]]]]]]`, some time PLUS
3. Has to press <kbd>esc</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> until the auto-type activity becomes idle for a while just in time to provide my password
4. It actively switch from one application to another application and has to press <kbd>esc</kbd> button continuously until the activity becomes idle
5. Scanning with Avast didn't find any viruses.

It’s very difficult to write anything on the text area or test box or anywhere. This happens every time, every day. But, at sometimes my system works normally and keyboard works normal but it last for 1 or 2 days (sometimes 1 week) only. And it again appears the same problem after few days. Someone suggested me that its a problem with Battery.

I believe this could be a virus since this same problem is happening on my brother’s laptop as well.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: it is laptop, I plugged external Keyboard still showing the same problem.

Comment: When you plug in the external keyboard the internal one is still connected, so the problem wouldn't be expected to go away.  This sound like a standard "stuck key" problem, possibly due to crud (or beverage) in the keyboard.

Comment: You may be able to clear the problem by intensively "exercising" the keyboard, striking all the keys repeatedly.

Comment: Besides, if the system is beeping at startup, then this is happening during POST and therefore is a hardware issue, not a virus.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it is a keyboard problem.

Try to find a replacement keyboard on Amazon for your laptop model or simply go on your nearest computer hardware store and give them to fix it for you.

In any way, you will have to pay for it because it is most probably damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a virus that causes this sort of behavior.  I've seen multiple dirty keyboards exhibit this problem, though.  Plugging in an external keyboard doesn't disable the internal one so the behavior continues.

Get a replacement, pay someone to install it if you're not comfortable doing such things (and note that laptops are a pain to work with.  I've had to replace mine once, IIRC something like an hour with Google and then an hour doing it--and I'm comfortable with building my own computers with barely glancing at the manuals.)